# Получение списка возможностей (capabilities) для устройств видео ввода

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg

Пытаюсь воспользоваться нововведениями в FFmpeg 2.7 C API для получения списка поддерживаемых кодеков, видеоформатов и видеоразрешений для каждого из устройств видеозахвата. Сам список устройств формирую следующим образом:

```
AVInputFormat *av_inp_fmt = NULL;
while((av_inp_fmt = av_input_video_device_next(av_inp_fmt))) {
    //av_inp_fmt->name
    //av_inp_fmt->long_name

    AVDeviceInfoList *av_dev_nfo_lst = NULL;
    if(avdevice_list_input_sources(av_inp_fmt, NULL, NULL, &av_dev_nfo_lst) >= 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i < av_dev_nfo_lst->nb_devices; ++i) {
            AVDeviceInfo *av_dev_nfo = av_dev_nfo_lst->devices[i];
            //av_dev_nfo->device_name
            //av_dev_nfo->device_description
        }
    }
}
```

Закоментированные в приведённом коде позиции переношу в модель и получаю такого рода результат:

[image: Пример вывода кода, формирующего список устройств]

Далее необходимо по каждому из устройств получить список его возможностей (форматов, кодеков и т.п.), однако с этим возникли проблемы. На странице FFmpeg 2.7 C API, относящейся к обозначенной теме, имеется [пример использования](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structAVDeviceCapabilitiesQuery.html) `AVDeviceCapabilitiesQuery`, однако он приведён лишь для устройства вывода, тогда как меня интересует исключительно устройство ввода.

Проблема заключается в получении `AVFormatContext`, который, в случае с устройством ввода, не имеет функции-аналога для `avformat_alloc_output_context2()`.

`AVFormatContext` для устройства ввода можно получить функцией `avformat_open_input()`, однако это не ведёт к профиту, поскольку функция `avdevice_capabilities_create()` с использованием данного контекста формата не возвращает список значений искомых параметров.

Можно было бы предположить, что `AVDeviceCapabilitiesQuery` предназначен исключительно для устройств вывода, однако, как отмечено в документации, данная часть API основана на `AVOption`, который при непосредственном использовании даёт возможность получить доступ к искомым параметрам. Например, через него я устанавливал видеоразрешение для v4l2 устройства.

Таким образом, получается, либо API пока ещё недоделано (на самом деле вносятся новые изменения в libavdevice от версии к версии), либо я неправильно понимаю использование `AVDeviceCapabilitiesQuery` для устройств ввода.

Прошу помочь с этим вопросом, если кто-нибудь сталкивался и сумел найти решение.

**Обновление.**

Использование `AVDictionary` напрямую также не даёт возможности получить список ключей ни с одним из устройств ввода.

```
AVFormatContext *av_fmt_ctx = NULL;
AVDictionary    *av_dict = NULL;
avformat_open_input(&av_fmt_ctx, av_dev_nfo->device_name, av_inp_fmt, &av_dict);

avformat_find_stream_info(av_fmt_ctx, &av_dict);

qDebug() << av_dict_count(av_dict); // Выводит 0.

AVDictionaryEntry *av_dict_entry = NULL;
while((av_dict_entry = av_dict_get(av_dict, "", av_dict_entry, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX))) {
    qDebug() << av_dict_entry->key << av_dict_entry->value;
}
```

Ключи не выводятся как если бы их не было. При этом в том же враппере у FFmpeg для устройств v4l2 имеется `AVOption`, и установка значения по ключу, взятому из исходников, например так, вполне себе работает:

```
// Устанавливает видеоразрешение v4l2-устройства на указанное.
av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "1280x720", 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это тот случай, когда нужно проверять коды возвращаемых ошибок. В данном случае: -38, Function not implemented.

Если посмотрите на код `avdevice_capabilities_create()`, то обнаружите, что оно обращается к `ctx->iformat->create_device_capabilities` которое для video4linux2 - NULL.

Ну и это, как бы сущность самого формата, а не конкретного устройства.

Входной же контекст для целей опроса получить просто:

```
AVFormatContext *inctx = avformat_alloc_context();
inctx->iformat = av_inp_fmt;
inctx->oformat = nullptr;
```

потом, как капсы получите и обработаете, можете открыть контекст. Только бесмысленно это (см ниже).

Да и вообще, судя по текущему положению дел (master бранч в git FFmpeg), это незаконченная вещь: ни одного AVInputFormat, у которого было бы установлено это поле, нет. Плюс не совсем логично и ясно, как быть в случае входа, но когда устройство ещё не открыто, ведь, по сути, капсы нужны, что бы правильно задать параметры словаря при открытии устройства (собственно комментарий к самой функции на это и намекает). Предполагаю, что для этих целей нужно будет создавать Input Context, как я выше, плюс задавать имя файла:

```
strncpy(inctx->name, "/dev/video0", sizeof(inctx->name));
```

что бы получить капсы конкретного устройства: те же вебки могут быть разными!

Сами же приватные ключи (но не значения!) формата можно посмотреть так:

```
const AVOption *cur = nullptr;
while ((cur = av_opt_next(&av_inp_fmt->priv_class, cur)) != nullptr) {
    clog << "  opt: " << cur->name << endl;
}
```

А так, вы не правы:

```
AVDictionary    *av_dict = NULL;
avformat_open_input(&av_fmt_ctx, av_dev_nfo->device_name, av_inp_fmt, &av_dict);
```

Согласно документации, на выходе в ненулевом av_dict будут содержаться те параметры, которые НЕ смогли обработаться, точнее не были найдены по ключу.

Comment: Спасибо. Содержательный и полезный ответ. Поведение `avformat_open_input()` в случае с `AVDictionary` лично для меня было не вполне понятно.

Comment: Вам спасибо за вопрос. Я, как бы, неплохо во внутрянке ffmpeg разбираюсь, но за всеми нововведениями следить не получается. А некоторое пригождается в части упрощения кода моего AvCpp (C++11 враппер для библиотек ffmpeg, но пилится медленно, хотя, по сути, остро сейчас не хватает только фильтров).